# Bash regex for a single \n ASCII character on a blank line

Tags: regex, bash, unix, ascii

I need a regex to match a line where we only have 1 **\n** non-printable ASCII character so:

```
[[ $line=~ REGEX ]]
```

Please help. The ASCII code for the character is **`(0x0A)`** and I know it should be something like: `^(0x0A)$`  but I can't get it to work.

EDIT

My code is:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ $line =~ REGEX ]] && printf "SUCCESS"
done < file
```

EDIT - this is the file, there is more code but I cut it out

[image]

file: https://ufile.io/88965

Comment: In many cases, this would be considered an empty line, so it would match `[[ -z $line ]]`. Please [edit] your question to explain how `$line` is assigned and what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: `\n` could be a line end, therefore actually regex `^$` should work. And now that I am thinking about it, Tom Fenech should be right about it being "an empty line".

Comment: \x0a should be ok

Comment: Upload your file somewhere. No picture.

Comment: Your file contains windows carriage returns. Use `dos2unix 88965-testche.dat` to convert.

Comment: `tr -d '\r' < 88965-testche.dat > testche.dat`

Comment: Use the correct path to the file, in that case! But all of this is sounding more and more like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/), so you should probably explain what you **really** want to do, which I assume isn't to print "SUCCESS" when you match a line in a file.

Comment: @Cyrus It worked thank you you saved my life !!!!!!!

Comment: @Cyrus is there some other way to deal with the problem (not involving dos2unix). My lecturer doesn't allow external programmes. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `while read` loop is reading your file until it finds a newline character, then assigning what it has read so far to `line`, discarding the newline.

You should therefore be able to detect empty lines like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    [[ -z $line ]] && printf "SUCCESS\n"
done < file
```

If you really want to use a regular expression, you can use `^$`, as suggested by others in the comments.

If your aim is to produce some kind of output when a line matches a pattern, you should be using a tool designed for this purpose, such as awk:

```
awk '/^$/ { print "SUCCESS" }' file
```

Since it seems that you have issues with Windows-style newlines, you can convert them to UNIX-style ones by using `dos2unix` or another tool to remove the carriage returns.

Comment: @zdrkp: Replace `< file` by `< <(dos2unix < 88965-testche.dat)`.

Comment: worked fine. Thank you all, the addition in the comment suggested by Cyrus in combination with [[ -z $line ]] made it work.

Comment: That's great but it's not clear whether you really want to change the format of your line endings as @Cyrus has suggested.

Comment: @TomFenech Is there another way to fix the problem? Turns out my lecturer doesn't allow usage of external programmes.

Comment: Since I don't completely understand what the problem is, I'm not sure. If you edit your question to make it more clear, maybe I or someone else can help you.

Comment: @TomFenech I made a new post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351042/get-past-carriage-returns-in-bash-without-changing-original-file